# how can I monitor Jboss threads to see the response times and waiting times in real time

Tags: performance, jboss, threads, response-time

We are facing a problem of slowness in performance when the requests are being served from JBoss. We had a web server routing requests to application server and we could see the problem with JBoss's JVM.

how can I monitor Jboss threads to see the response times and waiting times in real time?

Is there any tool which helps to see what are all the threads running (say at a regular perios of two seconds ) and their response times.?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jVisualVM](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html). It is part of the SUN/Oracle JDK, but can also be downloaded as separate program.

It has a tab for the thread overview and also some other metrics (Heap, Overview, ...). You can even connect from remote to your JBoss when you've enabled JMX.

I haven't used it for JBoss, but for Tomcat, should be nearly the same.